# Objective-C iOS 6 delegate NSString query

Tags: objective-c, ios6, delegates, nsstring, viewwillappear

I'm trying to use a delegate to pass a value from one VC to another. I think I'm am misunderstanding the way it is supposed to work.

In my main ViewController.h I have this:

```
@protocol defaultLocationChoice <NSObject>

- (NSString *) locChoice;

@end
```

In both my PreferencesViewController.h and ChooseServerViewController.h I have `defaultLocationChoice` declared in the @interface section and the property assinged like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <defaultLocationChoice> locationDelegate;
```

Both are synthesized also.

When the user segues from PreferencesViewController to ChooseServerViewController the prepare for segue code is:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toServerChoice"]) {
        ChooseServerViewController *viewController = (ChooseServerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.locationDelegate = self;

    }

}
```

When a cell choice is made in ChooseServerViewController I call:

```
[self locChoice];
```

Which is:

```
- (NSString *) locChoice {
    NSLog(@"Cell Vale Loc choice %@",cellValue);
    return cellValue;
}
```

The NSLog verifies the correct value is returned.

**Now, as I think I understand it, the value of LocChoice in the delegate is now the value returned, no?**

When the user goes back (NavController) the PreferencesViewController has:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    defaultLocation = [locationDelegate locChoice];
    [self.tableView reloadData];  
}
```

I was expecting the value of defaultLocation to now equal the value passed to locChoice. However when the table reloads the cell in question is still blank, implying what I exepct to happen isn't happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you logged defaultLocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I followed your code properly, you do not need to adopt the mentioned protocol in your `ChooseServerViewController`, only `PreferencesViewController`.

The reasoning is you want to send data **back** to the previous view controller. Try:

```
@protocol defaultLocationChoice <NSObject>
    - (void) locChoice:(NSString*)choice;
@end
```

Have your `PreferencesViewController` implement that method so it **receives** the selection. You will have to store that in an appropriate instance variable.

```
// in PreferencesViewController.m
-(void)locChoice:(NSString*)choice {
    self.choice = choice;  // this just my example
}
```

When the choice is made (in `ChooseServerViewController`) to send the choice back, call:

```
// this is in 'ChooseServerViewController.m' some where appropriate
[self.delegate locChoice:cellValue];
```

Your implementation is simply doing nothing with cell value (not even storing it, just logging it). When you return to `PreferencesViewController`, you will now have the selected value and that view controller can what it wants with it.

Protocols are somewhat analgous to interfaces in Java or C#, but more flexible.

- [Some more concepts about delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html).
- [Working with Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).

**UPDATE**:

The declaration for `ChooseServerViewController` should look like:

```
#import "FileWithProtocolDecalration.h"
@interface ChooseServerViewController
.
.
.
@property ( nonatomic,assign) id<defaultLocationChoice> delegate;
.
.
.
@end
```

Comment: My ChooseServerViewController complains that I'm not implementing a required protocol?

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer That view controller does not need to implement it, so in the .h remove the section `<defaultLocationChoice>`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I did try that but it then complained about my PrepareForSegue code as it couldn't find the locationDelegate in ChooseServerViewController and the self.delegate threw up and error that it couldn't find "delegate"

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer, please see my answer. you dont have `delegate` you have `[self.locationDelegate locChoice:cellValue];` like in here `@property (nonatomic, assign) id <defaultLocationChoice> locationDelegate;`

Comment: Ahh so all I had to do was remove the defaultLocationChoice from the @interface of the .h file but KEEP the property. Got it, thank you! All working and now I can clean up some other areas! Thanks again

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer Yep. I really recommend the two links I gave, delegates and protocols are used all over the Foundation and UIKit libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do have some misunderstanding there

protocol and delegates are something that is passed around. in other words somebody need to be receiver and somebody need to be the sender. in your case.
update your protocol to this

```
@protocol defaultLocationChoice <NSObject>

- (void)locChoice:(NSString *)updateString;  // the method from delegate and implementer must be exact

@end
```

and set implement the protocol to ViewController as a receiver

```
@interface VCReceiver : UIViewController <defaultLocationChoice>
```

then later in VCReceiver

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {  
    ChooseServerViewController *vcSender = [[ChooseServerViewController alloc] init];
    [vcSender setLocationDelegate:self]; // this is like saying. i have implemented method from protocol in this file (self)
}
- (void)locChoice:(NSString *)updateString {
    // update the VCReceiver here
    // or access vcSender value 
    // or use the updateString value
}
```

then in `ChooseServerViewController locChoice:` method (the one from your example) replace with this one and call `[self updateChoice]` instead:

```
- (void)updateChoice {
    if ([self.locationDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(locChoice:)]) {
         [self.locationDelegate locChoice:aStringToUpdate]; // this will call VCReceiver locChoice
   }
```

it does not have to return anything because it is actually calling the VCReceiver method to tell it that `ChooseServerViewController` got the value ready to be read.